# Get number of pictures using URL and Directory.GetFiles

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to get the number of pictures that is in a folder on a website. But I can't find a way to do it.

I have tried to use

```
string a = Request.QueryString["nr"];
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"URL" + a, a + "_profil*");
```

But it doesn't work. I get the error:

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: URI formats are not supported.

Comment: On remote or current website? If current use Server.MapPath()

Answer (score 2):

It is expecting the path to the folder on the file system, e.g. `c:\some\folder\`. Depending on what you're doing, you might be able to use `Server.MapPath("~/some/folder")` to resolve the full path.